# Оценить сложность функции

Tags: java, алгоритм, сложность

Есть функция которая перебирает в цикле входящий массив строк.

Внутри перебора вызывается метод который каждый элемент массива превращает в массив символов, сортирует `Arrays.sort` и уже отсортированный записывает в новую коллекцию.

пример на вход идет `{"acb","20","zoa"}`

на выходе `{"abc","02","aoz"}`

Как оценить сложность такой функции.

Comment: `O(n*m*log(m))`

Comment: зависит от сложности алгоритма сортировки

Comment: Перебор циклом из N элементов это n* , массив символов это m - длина строки, сортировка обычно оценивается как m\*Logm, в случае со строк, итого получаем n\*(m + mlogm). Старший член это n\*m\*logm. Тогда сложность O(n\*m\*log(m))

Comment: код пришлите алгоритма тогда скажем сложность